# Check if application has newest data using Vapor 3

Tags: postgresql, fluent, vapor

I'm making a form for adding questions to a quizapp, using Vapor 3.

What i want to do is:

- send the question to the "Question" table on the Database (Done)
- update a second table with "DB version" simultaneous/right after

The form is presented with Leaf

```
<form action="/save" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload-form">
```

And uses Vapor Route to fire a create method

```
func create(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<Response> {

    return try req.content.decode(ImageUpload.self).flatMap { image in

        if image.image?.filename != "", let img = image.image {

            let uploadDir = try req.sharedContainer.make(DirectoryConfig.self).workDir + "Public/Uploads/"

            let uploadURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: uploadDir + img.filename)
            try image.image?.data.write(to: uploadURL)

        }

        return try req.content.decode(Question.self).flatMap { question in

            if image.image?.filename != "", let img = image.image{
                question.imageName = img.filename
            }

            question.timestamp = Date()

            return question.save(on: req).map { _ in
                return req.redirect(to: "/dbVersion")
            }
        }

    }
```

And a Update method

```
func update(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<Response> {



    return try req.parameters.next(Question.self).flatMap { question in
        return try req.content.decode(questionForm.self).flatMap { questionForm in
            question.questionText = questionForm.questionText
            question.answers[0] = questionForm.alt0
            question.answers[1] = questionForm.alt1
            question.answers[2] = questionForm.alt2
            question.answers[3] = questionForm.alt3
            question.theme = questionForm.theme
            question.subject = questionForm.subject
            question.timestamp = Date()

            return question.save(on: req).map { _ in
                return req.redirect(to: "/form")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can i run update/create db version inside these methods?

Or could i just run these consecutively, on the same action? :

```
protectedRouter.post("save", use: questionController.create)
protectedRouter.post("save", use: databaseController.create)
```

Comment: I don't quite follow the second part of the question. If the create function works, what table does the second table do and what's the purpose of updating it?

Comment: Would a transaction work for you? https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/fluent/transaction/

There's also a global `map(Future<A>, Future<B>)` that might work for you where you could do something like `map(question.save(on: req), databaseVersion.save(on: req))`

Comment: @Jonnny The second table contains a version number, that i want to update every time a question is created, updated or deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the update. This isn't a strictly Vapor approach, but I'd argue it's probably the cleaner/easiest. Although, I'm not entirely sure the reason why you'd need to do this in general or what benefit it provides? :). I'd create a second table as you have, but use a Database trigger. That way, any time a row is updated you can "trigger" the update in your second table. Here's the relevant [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-trigger.html), Here's some untested code. If it doesn't work, find me in the Vapor Discourse and I can help, if you choose this approach.

```
CREATE TABLE questions (
    question text,
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE db_version (
    id serial,
    db_version_date timestamp
);

CREATE FUNCTION update_version() RETURNS trigger AS $update_version$
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO db_version SELECT now() ;
        RETURN NULL; -- result is ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
    END;

$update_version$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER update_version AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON questions
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_version();
```